# LaTeX is compiling the file from before changes

Tags: errors, compiling

I'm using `LaTeX` under `OSX 10.8.2`, `TeXworks` as an editor.

Searching solution for my problem I'm trying to compile differet codeds posted here in questions or answers. I've created few `test` files where I copy-paste the code I want to try. I've realised that if I delete all and paste completly new code, `LaTeX` gives me errors like it was trying to compile a new document together with the old one. Saving file after delete but before copy new content, even closing it and opening again, doesn't help, I have to create each time a new `test` file.

I have never encounter this problem working "normaly" on my documents, only now when I often get error messages (when I try to change the code as it fits my needs).

As an example, when I try to compile this:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
 \usepackage{polyglossia}

\newcommand*{\glossaryname}{Dictionary}
\usepackage[nonumberlist,xindy]{glossaries}
\newcommand{\dictentry}[3]{%
 \newglossaryentry{#1}%
{%
name=#1,
description={#2 & #3}}%
\glslink{#1}{}%
}

 \makeglossaries
\setmainlanguage{polish}

\begin{document}
\dictentry{on}{bal}{ggg} %
\dictentry{ja}{ccc}{ddd} %
\dictentry{pies}{zzzz}{abc} %

\printglossary[style=super]%
\end{document}
```

I get the following error:

> (./15.gls
>
> ! Undefined control sequence.
>
> Dr.\space \DTLinitials
>
> {Aardvark}\space Foobar
>
> l.5 ...etentrycounter[]{page}\glsnumberformat{1}}}
>
> %
>
> ?

I'm not saying that the file I'm trying to compile is fine, but `Dr.\space\DTLinitials{Aardvark}\space Foobar` is not part of this file at all, but of the previous one...

I thought it's maybe because `LaTeX` is stil reffering to the files created by `makeglossaries`, so I wanted to run it again, but it was impossible since `LaTeX` failed to compile the file.

Probably I'm just omiting something obvious, but I have no idea why it happens.

EDIT:

Trying advices given to me in comments, I've tried:

1. Delete all auxiliary files before running `LaTeX`. Indeed it works, but looks a bit complicated for me for testing solutions - since I'm learning, so doing a lot of misteakes, I should delete auxiliary files after each attempt of improveing the code.
2. Type `r` when LaTeX stops compilation. Than `LaTeX` continue compiling, but first - I have to retype it each time I run LaTeX again on the same file, even if I didn't change it, second - the output is not the output that should be generated - two different files with exactly the same input gives different output.

Comment: You can try deleting the various auxiliary files created by previous runs of latex.

Comment: Try press `r` and `return`.

Comment: @T.Verron Thanks, indeed it helps. But first, I thought that the auxiliary files are overwritten each time I run LaTeX, second, I'm trying to learn new things, so I get error messages almost all the time, if I have to enter the folder to delete all auxiliary files after each compilation it starts to be a bit complicated. If there is no other solution, I'd have to, but why never before I had to do this?

Comment: @Sigur You mean in the terminal? I did, several times, but it just interrupt the compilation and next time I try exactly the same happens... Thanks anyway :)

Comment: @maria, sorry. I'm almost sleeping. My fault. Please, try `r`.

Comment: @maria, sometimes, before to create another auxiliary files it must to read the old ones, so some errors could appear. If you type `r` you continue the process and the new auxiliary file is created.

Comment: @Sigur Ok, I have `t1.tex` and `t2.tex`, both were "blocked". When I type `r` in the terminal, LaTeX ends the compilation, but when I made copy-paste of `t1.tex` to `t2.tex` the output is not the same as it should...

Comment: @Sigur If I try to compile again one of this files I have to tape `r` each time, even if I didn't change the file after first compilation.

Comment: @maria, try to run directly from terminal (not using editor). Type `latex t1.tex` or `pdflatex t1.tex` if you want a PDF file. You have to open the folder containing your file. If you don't know how to use terminal, try to google it. ps: are you from Poland? I miss Poland winter.

Comment: @Sigur The same happens if I compile using TeXworks button or in the terminal. I am from Poland and I hate polish winter :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6685/discussion-between-sigur-and-maria)

Comment: You can delete auxiliary files from within TeXworks: `File->Remove Aux Files`.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Thanks a lot. But is it normal, what is going on? I mean, I had never had this problem before...

Comment: Sometimes information from a previous document is still in the auxiliary files and will conflict with a new document, so you need to remove the aux files.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Is there a way of compile .tex file from the terminal that has an option to remove auxiliary files after compilation?

Comment: @maria The problem is exactly that you are copying arbitrary code into one and the same `.tex` file, but the auxiliary files "assume" that the preamble of your document stays the same between runs. For instance, package `babel` puts a marker into the `.aux` to signify the document language. So if you have `babel` in the preamble on one run, but not on the next, TeX will complain that the marker makes no sense if you haven't loaded `babel`.

Answer (score 9):

This is a property of LaTeX itself. Some of the information in `.aux` file is sensitive to changes in the document, especially changes in:

- `babel` loading and languages
- `hyperref` loading

If you consider it simplest to use the same file name, I recommend you to always run LaTeX on this simple document in between:

```
\batchmode
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Hello World!
\end{document}
```

It should clear the information in the auxiliary files and everything should run smoothly.

---

*Obviously, much simpler solution is to use the TeXworks built-in command*

> *File -> Remove Aux Files...*

*whenever you paste a new MWE.*